# How do the reformed view the "Left Behind" series?

Tags: reformed-theology, eschatology, christian-literature

Are the teachings of Tim LaHaye as found in the *[Left Behind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_Behind)* series consistent with the teachings of either reformed theology or Calvinism?

More generally, is the notion of "Biblical Fiction" considered as something that would help or mislead the reader?

Comment: Does Biblical Fiction mislead the reader? Does Pope live in Papal Apartments near St. Peter's Basilica in Vatican City?

Comment: Here's the situation: I recently bought "The End" (a book on revelation) by Mark Hitchcock (a pastor somewhere); the book itself looks nice, then I flip the front cover, and it's praise comes from Tim Lahaye, author of the left behind series. Now I'm wondering what to do with this book.

Comment: @user1311390 Read it.  And evaluate it on its merits.

Comment: I'll just add one comment: Jesus Himself used "biblical fiction". What else is a parable?

Comment: @user131: Considering that 1) we each have a limited number of hours for reading, and 2) there's thousands of years worth of solid Christian literature out there, you might choose to invest your time in reading other teachers instead -- maybe Piper, or Sproul. Or Augustine, Luther, or Calvin. Or plenty of others. For example, here's a [*site*](http://www.ccel.org/) that could keep anyone busy. In any event, it's good to see that you're actively studying. Cheers.

Comment: I must say that reading [Slacktivist's analysis of *Left Behind*](http://slacktivist.typepad.com/archives/2011/08/left-behind-at-patheos.html) has done a great deal to give me a better impression of Christians in general (and a worse impression of Ellenjay in particular).

Comment: @TriG: I've only read a few of the posts. it gave me an interesting impression of the authors of the Left Behind entries; but how did it change your impressions of Christians in general?

Comment: @user1311390. Well, the blog is written by a Christian, and the commenting community that grew up around the blog also contains many Christians. Slacktivist's *Left Behind* analysis, and the other posts on the blog, show me a side of Christianity full of decent people who want to change the world for the better. It's easy to miss those Christians when you follow the news. Most in the news are actively trying to make the world less fair, less just, selling fear and claiming the moral high ground while they do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No.** The Left Behind series is A) entirely fictional and B) based on Dispensationalism.*

[Dispensationalism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dispensationalism) is almost universally at odds with [Reformed theology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformed-theology). The basic problem lies in the understanding of the way God relates to his people. Understanding this relationship in the context of [covenants](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covenants) that get renewed with unfolding detail but don't fundamentally change (a defining feature of Reformed and Calvinistic theology) is substantially different and at odds with an understanding it which God's relation to men is set in the context of separate dispensations each with their own distinct characteristics.

Calvanism is not quite as broad a structure as Reformed theology and it is harder to draw a correlation to eschatology just from the points that it considers, but I think it is fair to lump them in together because it basically sets the stage for Reformed theology.

There are a few groups that use the label "Reformed" as an adjective rather than a noun. Rather than being "Reformed" they are "Reformed X" where X is something else. By this they could mean a variety of things, but usually it means they have incorporated some of the doctrines considered Calvinistic or some of the practices developed by Reformed churches, but they still hold onto another identity as their primary doctrinal framework. Among these are some groups who would hold to a Dispensational/Premillenial eschatology, but these are definitely a minority among those using the label "Reformed".

A key aspect of your question is that you asked about the "teachings". Even as somebody who disagrees with the interpretation from beginning to end, as a mental exercise in reading fiction -- reading with the same eye as I would read Tolkien or watch Batman -- it is possible to enjoy the the books as apocalyptic fiction.

However I agree with your labeling them as "teachings" because at the end of the day, without a strong theological background, it is almost impossible to listen to the Bible talked about and real verses analyse and commented on even inside a fictional setting and not take away something. The author is a professing Christian, the books match his own theology and he has made every claim of intending the books as a way to further people's understanding of Christianity.

As such, I think it is fair that the contents be treated with the same scrutiny that a theology textbook would be. It is, after all, more theological than anything many professing Christians will bother to study.

In this light, it is worth noting that even some modern Dispensational Premillenialists take issue with the some of the interpretation work that is scattered between the pages pure fiction. As for anybody with a different eschatology, it is almost inconceivable that they could even stomach the read.

<sub>* Please note I am refraining from commenting on whether A==B.</sub>

Comment: The main teaching of the books (this is based on my [vicarious reading through Slacktivist](http://slacktivist.typepad.com/archives/2011/08/left-behind-at-patheos.html)) seems to be that God is a complete and utter bastard, and that empathy is non-Christian. I'm sure many other Christians would dispute this, though perhaps not quite so thoroughly as Fred Clark.

Comment: "it is possible to enjoy the the books as apocalyptic fiction" -- I hope you mean this in the abstract, hypothetical sense... and not in the sense of "I've read this book, and consider it to be good, entertaining literature" :P